# How to parse data by subtituting part of a url

Tags: python, csv, urllib2

I have a list saved in a csv file, and I'd like to download some data from a website, like this:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23626827

I would like to write a python script to open the url, and the from the csv file where I have stored the list of the numbers, which is after pubmed/, download all the data into an other csv file.

So I have to use urllib2, loops and strings, but I just cant get it right.

Im not asking for a whole script, just please help me starting it, or give an idea.

Many thanks!

Comment: Try to explain more clearly please. What do the numbers in the csv file represend? What data do you want to download? what is "pubmed"?

Comment: This site works best when you post your code and explain how it isn't doing what you are expecting.

Comment: Sorry. Pubmed is a website which contains articles. And the number is the ID of the article. I want to download the whole content.

Comment: Download all data and store in CSV? Really? Want to store technical articles in CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example on how to read input csv with numbers (IDs) via `csv`, load the content via `urllib2`, parse the content via `lxml` and write to the output csv file:

```
import urllib2
import csv
import lxml.html


URL = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/"

# read IDs from the input csv file
with open('input.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    numbers = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(csvfile)]

# get the article and collect it's title for each ID
output = []
for number in numbers:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(URL + number)
    html = response.read()

    tree = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
    output.append(tree.xpath('//div[@class="rprt abstract"]/h1')[0].text)

# write article titles to the output csv
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in output:
        csvwriter.writerow([row])
```

`input.csv` content:

```
23626827
23626828
23626829
```

You'll get article titles on each row in the `output.csv`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

to read csv file and get data :

```
f=open('yourCSV.csv','rb')
try:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   for row in reader:
       print row[0]
finally:
   f.close()
```

then add it to URL